# How come my SESSIONS aren't saving?

Tags: php, session

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    <title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<style>
    .login-panel {
        margin-top: 150px;

</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="admin_login.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group"  >
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="admin_name" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="admin_pass" type="password" value="">
                            </div>


                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="login" name="admin_login" >


                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>

<?php
include("database/db_conection.php");

if(isset($_POST['admin_login']))//this will tell us what to do if some data has been post through form with button.
{
    $admin_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['admin_name']);
    $admin_pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['admin_pass']);

    $admin_query="select * from users WHERE user_name='$admin_name' AND user_pass='$admin_pass' AND admin='true'";

    $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$admin_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query))
    {
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        $_SESSION['adminName']=$admin_name;
        $_SESSION['isAdmin']='true';
    }
    else {echo"<script>alert('Admin Details are incorrect..!')</script>";}

}

?>
```

That is from my `admin_login.php` page, and inside the `db_connection.php` is just code to connect to the users database

I have tried putting the SESSION variables above the echo to `welcome.php`, but not even that worked.

In case you are still confused, the `$_SESSION['adminName']=$admin_name;` and `$_SESSION['isAdmin']='true';` are not setting correctly, and I have no clue why.

Comment: You never start the session... http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function

```
session_start();
```

somewhere before using the `$_SESSION`globals. [Here's the documentation about it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)!

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate the quick response. I will read up on the documentation just so that I'm familiar with everything.

Comment: No problem! PHP can be tricky sometimes but the documentation always does a good job at explaining how it works.